# async componentDidMount not executing in React native

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, expo

I'm trying to make component called CacheImage that will save image to cache. This component receive **url address** and **style** as parameter and return Image component with particular url and styling. I'm using firebase storage for storing images.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Image } from 'react-native';
import shorthash from 'expo'
import { FileSystem } from 'expo';

export default class CacheImage extends React.Component {
  state = {
    source: null,
  };

  componentDidMount = async () => {
    const { uri } = this.props;
    const name = shorthash.unique(uri);
    alert(name);
    const path = `${FileSystem.cacheDirectory}${name}`;
    const image = await FileSystem.getInfoAsync(path);
    if (image.exists) {
      alert('read image from cache');
      this.setState({
        source: {
          uri: image.uri,
        },
      });
      return;
    }

    alert('downloading image to cache');
    const newImage = await FileSystem.downloadAsync(uri, path);
    this.setState({
      source: {
        uri: newImage.uri,
      },
    });
  };

  render() {
    return <Image style={this.props.style} source={this.state.source} resizeMode='cover'/>;
  }
}
```

But for some reason program won't even go inside componentDidMount. I'm newbie in react native so maybe I'm missing something obvious. Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an async function and call it in `componentDidMount`.

```
componentDidMount() {
    const asyncFunction = async () => {
      const { uri } = this.props;
      const name = shorthash.unique(uri);
      alert(name);
      const path = `${FileSystem.cacheDirectory}${name}`;
      const image = await FileSystem.getInfoAsync(path);
      if (image.exists) {
        alert('read image from cache');
        this.setState({
          source: {
            uri: image.uri,
          },
        });
        return;
      }

      alert('downloading image to cache');
      const newImage = await FileSystem.downloadAsync(uri, path);
      this.setState({
        source: {
          uri: newImage.uri,
        },
      });
    };

    asyncFunction();
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, seems like it's working now :)